# Run Macro in another excel, but fail to return to current sub after the called Macro completed

Tags: excel, vba

ParentExcel.xlsm has sub to call a sub in ChildExcel1.xlsm and ChildExcel2.xlsm

```
//in ParentExcel.xlsm    
Sub ParentSub()

    Set runWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=mChildPath)
    Application.Run runWorkbookName & "!" & ChildSub1

    /*Edit*/Set runWorkbook2 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=mChildPath2)
    Application.Run runWorkbookName2 & "!" & ChildSub2
End sub

//in ChildExcel1.xlsm
Sub ChildSub1()

     MsgBox "Called ChildSub1"
     /*Added*/ThisWorkbook.Close

End sub

//in ChildExcel2.xlsm
Sub ChildSub2()

     MsgBox "Called ChildSub2"
     /*Added*/ThisWorkbook.Close

End sub
```

My problem is, the procedure stopped after completion of ChildSub1() and the ChildExcel1.xlsm is closed. I then cannot execute the remaining code in the ParentSub()

Comment: I cannot get you... Why to be `ChildExcel1.xlsm` closed? Your code does  not close it. Both workbooks and calls are made in the same procedure. What do you want, in fact? To make it working with the workbooks, where the subs to be called, being closed? It would be possible to make such a call, using the workbook full path, but I would like to understand which is your real problem and I cannot...

Comment: sorry, I missed the "Close" line. I have added back

Comment: OK, but which is the problem? I asked in the above comment about what you want accomplishing... Do you want calling the sub **even if the workbook keeping the sub to be called is closed**? If not, what else do you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you close the Workbook where the code is in (runWorkbook), the execution stops (VBA is single threaded and with the close statement in ChildSub1 the runtime assumes you're done).

You will need to put the close statement into the calling routine - which is cleaner anyhow as with this, the routine that opens the workbook also closes it.

Note that you use `runWorkbookName` which is neiter defined nor set in the code you show us. You could use the following code instead:

```
Set runWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=mChildPath)
Application.Run runWorkbook.Name & "!" & ChildSub1
runWorkbook.Close 

Set runWorkbook2 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=mChildPath2)
Application.Run runWorkboo2.kName & "!" & ChildSub2
runWorkbook2.Close
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to **call subs from closed workbooks**, please use the next way. Using their full name will make the call opening the necessary workbook. If they will be already open, the code will work, too:

```
Sub ParentSub()
  dim mChildPath as string, mChildPath2 as string
  mChildPath = "full name of the workbook"         'please fill here the real path
  mChildPath2 = "full name of the second workbook" 'the same as above
    Application.Run "'" & mChildPath & "'!" & "ChildSub1"

    Application.Run "'" & mChildPath2 & "'!" & "ChildSub2"
End sub
```

Now, making the calls, the necessary workbooks will be open and they will be closed by their called `Sub`...